# Could not find com.github.MasayukiSuda:Mp4Composer-android:v0.3.9

Tags: android, flutter

while using tapioca 1.0.1 plugin inside flutter i am unable to build app it always fails with this error message coming..

Full Error

registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preReleaseBuild'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.github.MasayukiSuda:Mp4Composer-android:v0.3.9.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - file:/Users/x/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.pom
> - file:/Users/x/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.jar
> - file:/Users/x/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.pom
> - file:/Users/x/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.jar
> - file:/Users/x/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.pom
> - file:/Users/x/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.jar
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.pom
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.jar
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.jar
> - https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.pom
> - https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.jar
> - https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.pom
> - https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.jar
> - https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.pom
> - https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.jar
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.pom
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.jar
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.jar
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.pom
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.jar
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.jar
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.pom
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.jar
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.jar
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.pom
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.jar
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.jar
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.pom
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.jar
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.jar
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.pom
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.jar
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.jar
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.pom
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.jar
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.jar
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.pom
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.jar
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.jar
> - https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.pom
> - https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.jar
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.pom
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.jar
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.jar
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.pom
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.jar
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.jar
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.pom
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.jar
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.jar
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.pom
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.jar
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.jar
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.pom
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.jar
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/v0.3.9/Mp4Composer-android-v0.3.9.jar
> Required by:
> project :app > project :tapioca

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'... Done                        17.3s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 1):

Hello Guys i found the solution :

inside project level gradle file add this

```
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
```

it will work now

Answer (score 0):

ya add- maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
and also set the minSdkVersion to 21

Comment: can you please tell me where to put it exactly?

Comment: inside your project level build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

Add `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` like this,

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
   maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
  }
}
```

In Project level build.gradle,
add it in allprojects -> repositories.